# json rpc 2.0 in laravel api errors on add request

Tags: php, json, laravel, json-rpc

I add  https://github.com/sajya/server

for making json rpc over my laravel 8.

I just follow the instructions provided here to test it  https://sajya.github.io/docs/

All works for the basic example, But if I add params to the curl string an error is raised an error that i cannot understand:

my code:

```
<?php

declare(strict_types=1);

namespace App\Http\Procedures;
use Sajya\Server\Procedure;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class PharmaciesProcedure extends Procedure
{
    /**
     * The name of the procedure that will be
     * displayed and taken into account in the search
     *
     * @var string
     */
    public static string $name = 'pharmacies';


    public function ping(Request $request)
    {
        return $request->input('innings');
    }
}
```

my route api file:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;
use App\Http\Procedures\PharmaciesProcedure;


Route::rpc('/test1', [PharmaciesProcedure::class])->name('rpc.endpoint');
```

this request works:

> curl 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/test1' --data-binary
> '{"jsonrpc":"2.0","method":"pharmacies@ping","params":[],"id" : 1}'

This not:

> curl 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/test1' --data-binary
> '{"jsonrpc":"2.0","method":"pharmacies@ping","params":["innings": "out"],"id" : 1}'

the error:

> {"id":null,"error":{"code":-32700,"message":"Parse
> error","data":null,"file":"/home/natty/workspace/farmacie/vendor/sajya/server/src/Http/Parser.php","line":133,"trace":"#0
> /home/natty/workspace/farmacie/vendor/sajya/server/src/Http/Parser.php(104):
> Sajya\Server\Http\Parser->checkValidation()\n#1
> /home/natty/workspace/farmacie/vendor/sajya/server/src/Guide.php(49):
> Sajya\Server\Http\Parser->makeRequests()\n#2
> /home/natty/workspace/farmacie/vendor/sajya/server/src/JsonRpcController.php(27):
> Sajya\Server\Guide->handle()\n#3
> /home/natty/workspace/farmacie/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/ControllerDispatcher.php(48):
> Sajya\Server\JsonRpcController->__invoke()\n#4
> /home/natty/workspace/farmacie/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Route.php(255):
> Illuminate\Routing\ControllerDispatcher->dispatch()\n#5
> /home/natty/workspace/farmacie/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Route.php(197):
> Illuminate\Routing\Route->runController()\n#6
> /home/natty/workspace/farmacie/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php(691):
> Illuminate\Routing\Route->run()\n#7
> /home/natty/workspace/farmacie/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(128):
> Illuminate\Routing\Router->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}()\n#8
> /home/natty/workspace/farmacie/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Middleware/SubstituteBindings.php(41):
> Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}()\n#9
> /home/natty/workspace/farmacie/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(167):
> Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings->handle()\n#10
> /home/natty/workspace/farmacie/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Middleware/ThrottleRequests.php(127):
> Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}()\n#11
> /home/natty/workspace/farmacie/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Middleware/ThrottleRequests.php(103):
> Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\ThrottleRequests->handleRequest()\n#12
> /home/natty/workspace/farmacie/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Middleware/ThrottleRequests.php(55):
> Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\ThrottleRequests->handleRequestUsingNamedLimiter()\n#13
> /home/natty/workspace/farmacie/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(167):
> Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\ThrottleRequests->handle()\n#14
> /home/natty/workspace/farmacie/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(103):
> Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}()\n#15
> /home/natty/workspace/farmacie/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php(693):
> Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->then()\n#16
> /home/natty/workspace/farmacie/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php(668):
> Illuminate\Routing\Router->runRouteWithinStack()\n#17
> /home/natty/workspace/farmacie/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php(634):
> Illuminate\Routing\Router->runRoute()\n#18
> /home/natty/workspace/farmacie/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php(623):
> Illuminate\Routing\Router->dispatchToRoute()\n#19
> /home/natty/workspace/farmacie/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Kernel.php(166):
> Illuminate\Routing\Router->dispatch()\n#20
> /home/natty/workspace/farmacie/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(128):
> Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel->Illuminate\Foundation\Http\{closure}()\n#21
> /home/natty/workspace/farmacie/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/TransformsRequest.php(21):
> Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}()\n#22
> /home/natty/workspace/farmacie/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(167):
> Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\TransformsRequest->handle()\n#23
> /home/natty/workspace/farmacie/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/TransformsRequest.php(21):
> Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}()\n#24
> /home/natty/workspace/farmacie/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(167):
> Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\TransformsRequest->handle()\n#25
> /home/natty/workspace/farmacie/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/ValidatePostSize.php(27):
> Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}()\n#26
> /home/natty/workspace/farmacie/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(167):
> Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\ValidatePostSize->handle()\n#27
> /home/natty/workspace/farmacie/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/PreventRequestsDuringMaintenance.php(87):
> Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}()\n#28
> /home/natty/workspace/farmacie/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(167):
> Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\PreventRequestsDuringMaintenance->handle()\n#29
> /home/natty/workspace/farmacie/vendor/fruitcake/laravel-cors/src/HandleCors.php(57):
> Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}()\n#30
> /home/natty/workspace/farmacie/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(167):
> Fruitcake\Cors\HandleCors->handle()\n#31
> /home/natty/workspace/farmacie/vendor/fideloper/proxy/src/TrustProxies.php(57):
> Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}()\n#32
> /home/natty/workspace/farmacie/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(167):
> Fideloper\Proxy\TrustProxies->handle()\n#33
> /home/natty/workspace/farmacie/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(103):
> Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}()\n#34
> /home/natty/workspace/farmacie/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Kernel.php(141):
> Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->then()\n#35
> /home/natty/workspace/farmacie/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Kernel.php(110):
> Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel->sendRequestThroughRouter()\n#36
> /home/natty/workspace/farmacie/public/index.php(52):
> Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel->handle()\n#37
> /home/natty/workspace/farmacie/server.php(21):
> require_once('/home/natty/wor...')\n#38 {main}"},"jsonrpc":"2.0"}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there was an error on documentation, the developer of the libs suggest me to change:

> curl 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/test1' --data-binary
> '{"jsonrpc":"2.0","method":"pharmacies@ping","params":["innings":
> "out"],"id" : 1}'

to

> curl 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/test1' --data-binary
> '{"jsonrpc":"2.0","method":"pharmacies@ping","params":{"innings":
> "out"},"id" : 1}'

so changing [] to {} in "params" make it works!